# Print out the items which went through For loop? python 2.7

Tags: python, for-loop, arcpy

I am new in python. I have a `for loop` inside which I have `if ...:` condition.

I want to print out the (list) of items which went through the `for` loop.

Ideally, items should be separated by spaces or by commas. This is a simple example, intended to use with `arcpy` to print out the processed shapefiles.

Dummy example:

```
for x in range(0,5):
    if x < 3:
        print "We're on time " + str(x)
```

What I tried without success inside and outside of `if` and `for` loop:

```
print "Executed " + str(x)
```

Expected to get back (but not in `list` format), maybe through something like `arcpy.GetMessages()` ?

```
Executed 0 1 2
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.7, I have updated my question

Comment: ArcPy seems to be irrelevant to your question since none of the answers include it.

Comment: I've deleted the arcpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phrase = "We're on time "

# create a list of character digits (look into list comprehensions and generators)
nums = [str(x) for x in range(0, 5) if x < 3]

# " ".join() creates a string with the elements of a given list of strings with space in between
# the + concatenates the two strings
print(phrase + " ".join(nums))
```

Note. A reason for the downvotes could help us new users understand how things should be.

Comment: Thank you for your support for explaining the reasons for downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Record your `x`'s in a list and print out this list in the end:

```
x_list = []
for x in range(0,5):
    if x < 3:
        x_list.append(x)
        print "We're on time " + str(x)
print "Executed " + str(x_list)
```

Comment: I have an error back: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Thank you ! now it works. Is it possible to not to get the list of items back, but just 0 1 2?

Comment: A quick fix is to use `print "Executed " + str(x_list)[1:-1]`. This removes the first and last character (the `[` and the `]`) from the `str` representation of `x_list`.

Comment: Thank you ! I''ll check for another answer but I am happy to accept your solution as well:-D

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python3 you could just do something like this..

```
print("Executed ", end='')
for x in range(0,5):
    if x < 3:
        print(str(x), end=' ')
print()
```